# Knockout safari validation errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, knockout.js, safari

I was get project with knockout, but i have not expirience with knockout. 
And I get strange error in safari/ios (windows chrome and android chrome - all ok)

```js
origin: ko.observable().extend({
    required: {
        message: "Origin  is required."
    }
}),

var errors = ko.validation.group(this);
var lineErrors = ko.validation.group(this.lines, {
    deep: true,
    live: true
});
console.log(1, errors().length);
console.log(2, lineErrors().length);
```

In chrome i get

*1 - 0*

*2 - 0*

in safari i get

*1 - 2*

*2 - 0*

I try change *ko.validation.group(this, { deep: true, live: true })* - no affect

Field with error is text input with typeahead.

**Why?**

**Which differents between Safari/knockout and Chrome/knockout i must know?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change

```html
<input data-bind='value:origin'>
```

to

```html
<input data-bind='textInput:origin'>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do here since this code is taken out of context, but I'll take a shot in the dark here.

It's possible that the "this" in your line...

```
var errors = ko.validation.group(this);
```

...is interpreted differently in Chrome than it is in Safari.  Chrome may think it's referring to one object while Safari thinks it's another.

The "this" keyword in Javascript is very tricky and should be approached with caution.  One common practice to ensure that you're referring to the exact thing that you want to refer to is to assign "this" to some other in-scope variable that you can then reference with complete confidence that you are referring to the thing you think you are.  This is especially important if you're using closures, or otherwise functions within functions. 
 For example...

```
var someOuterFunction = function() {
    var outerFunction = this;

    var someInnerFunction = function() {
        var innerFunction = this;

        var doSomeWorkWithTheOuterAndInnerFunctions(outerFn, innerFn) {
            //Perform some sort of work with your functions
        }

        //Call a function that performs some sort of work with your nested functions 
        doSomeWorkWithTheOuterAndInnerFunctions(outerFunction, innerFunction);
    }
}
```

Creating and using the outerFunction and innerFunction variables is the key.  Setting your "this" explicitly to those variables and then using those variables instead will guarantee that you will be referencing the thing you think you are.

I hope that helps! :-)